# Can we change the text of the review audit failed message?

Tags: feature-request, review, review-audits

> STOP! Look and Listen. This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. You didn't pass. This question has serious problems that must be fixed before it can be answered. If you're unable to fix these problems by Editing, you should Close such questions. Don't worry, we've already handled this answer appropriately – but please take a minute to look it over closely, keeping in mind the guidance above.

There is a mis-match between question and answer. The text says that "this question has serious problems" but that "we've already handled this answer". Perhaps "post" would be more generic and suitable for both?

Everyone knows that you don't "STOP! Look and Listen!", but that you "STOP! Collaborate and Listen!" because Ice is back with his brand new invention.

Comment: +1 for the lulz alone on the last sentence

Comment: I kind of want to downvote for getting that song stuck in my head...

Comment: I am neither suitable nor generic enough for any situation involving Vanilla Ice. Post will not be a party to this tomfoolery, even on Friday.